# Stop redirecting to another page if the fields are empty in YII

Tags: php, yii

I am a newbee to yii and i am middle of something.
I have many forms in view page where i click on submit it check the fields and enter database.

But my question is if i have 5 different forms that need to check for validation and should stay in the same form which is entering another form.In the view page i kept active for li which it is redirects to the page which is active form. How should i stop redirecting to active page if the fields are empty and should stay in that particular page and check for validation.

IN the controller i have kept like this

```
if(isset($_POST['myform'])) 
{ 
    $valid = true; 
    foreach($_POST as $p) 
    { 
        if($p == null) 
        { 
            $valid = false; 
        } 
    } 
    if($valid)
    { 
        $model->save(); 
        $this->render('mypage',array('model'=>$model,'model1'=>$model1,'model2'=>$model2‌​,'model3'=>$model3,'model4'=>$model4)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Tou can enable client validation for all forms. so it'll show errors before form submit.

Comment: it seems multi-step form, and you want to fillout all form element on earlier step first to go to next one, right ?

Comment: yes @Ramakrishna. I have different forms in a single view page by default i have given to one form as active rest of them as fade. If you fill the form which is having fade and with blank texts if you submit it shows error but it is redirecting to the page which is active i need to stop it if the texts are empty and show the same form in the view page

Answer (score 0):

```
$valid = true;
foreach($_POST as $p){
   if($p == null){
        $valid = false;
   }
}

if($valid){
    $model->save();
    $this->redirect('yoururl');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I got the validation where the empty it shows an error but still it redirecting to same active page in li. I have in controller as like,

Comment: IN the controller i have kept like this
<br>
if(isset($_POST['myform']))

{ $valid = true;

        foreach($_POST as $p)
{ if($p == null) {

$valid = false;

}

}

        if($valid){
            $model->save();
            $this->render('mypage',array('model'=>$model,'model1'=>$model1,'model2'=>$model2,'model3'=>$model3,'model4'=>$model4));
        }

Comment: so, i didnt understand that where do you want to redirect it?

Comment: i have 5 different forms of different models like model,model1,model2,model3,model4. IF i click submit button which is in model4 it is getting validate ad showing errors but it is loading to the model(1stpage) not the model4 to which i have as active to model to show a default page but not as blank.

Comment: can you add the forms urls step by step pls... Or all forms have same url?

Comment: i have used only 1 render after it is saved and success

Comment: i have used only 1 render after it is saved and success.            public function actionMypage() 
{            if(isset($_POST['work'])){
if($model->validate()){ if($model->save()){ }
 }                                    if(isset($_POST['profile'])){
if($model1->validate()){if($model1->save()){ }}                                       if(isset($_POST['bussiness'])){if($model2->validate()) {if($model2->save()){
 }} // same like for model 2,3 and 4$this>render('mypage',array('model'=>$model,'model1'=>$model1,'mode2'=>$mode2,'mode3'=>$model3,'model4'=>$model4));   }

Comment: ok, i created a multiform like this 2 years ago. pls add your view file then wait for feedback ;)

Comment: @Vijay, Please update your questions with above code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        if(isset($_POST['myform'])) 
        {     
            if(count($_POST)==count(array_filter($_POST)))
            { 
                $model->save(); 
                $this->render('mypage',array('model'=>$model,'model1'=>$model1,'model2'=>$model2‌​,'model3'=>$model3,'model4'=>$model4)); 
            }
        }
```